# How to escape mysql database name to prevent sql injection in cakephp3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a requirement where i have to create new mysql database with the name provided by user through form. For now i have allowed only  `alphanumeric` characters for database name.

I think this `alphanumeric` validation on database name somehow protects me from `sql injection` but still i want to to prevent `sql injection` completely.  I have tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on user input but it's not escaping if user input is like this `new_db_name; DROP DATABASE other_database; --`.

So how can i escape `user input` so that it can be used safely for `databse name` preventing `sql injection`? I am using cakephp3 , i have tried following code in `cakephp3` which is not escaping user input like `new_db_name; DROP DATABASE other_database; --`

```
    $db = mysql_real_escape_string($user_input);
    $rootConnection = ConnectionManager::get('rootUserConnect');

    //i)using query method
    $rootConnection->query("CREATE DATABASE $db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");

    //ii) or using execute method , it's throwing mysql syntax error
    // $rootConnection->execute("CREATE DATABASE :db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci",['db' => $db]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Cake's ORM: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `quoteIdentifier()` function in the driver:

```
$rootConnection = ConnectionManager::get('rootUserConnect');
$db = $rootConnection->driver()->quoteIdentifier($db);
$root->connection->execute(...);
```

More information about this method: http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_quoteIdentifier

Comment: Just as a short note, it is not really a good idea to let users create your database names. It is better that you assign a controlled name, such as an unique id, and save in another database the relationship between the name the user intended and the real name that was assigned

Comment: @lorenzo Doesn't `quoteIdentifier()` only surrounds the string with backticks? I can't test it right now, but I think SQL injections would still be possible, like ``new_db_name`; DROP DATABASE other_database; --``. IIRC PDO doesn't support escaping/sanitizing of identifiers, so one will have to do that manually, like using a whitelist as you suggested, or if the user really needs to be able to choose the name, using a very strict regex that for example only allows ASCII letters.

Comment: @ndm Yes, that's why I suggested not letting the user select the db name

Comment: I see, I'm just bringing it up becase people will most probably think that you are saying that this actually prevents SQL injections, as this is what the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the query builder.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) You effectively ignore the ORM by what you're doing. One of the reasons to use an ORM is to prevent SQL injections. The ORM will take care of sanitizing the query for you.

There are a few cases in which a developer can still cause the possibility of an injection. [The manual tells you as well how to prevent that](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention).